# Adding rows of stats from two different tables to make a total row. SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have two rows of stats for a hockey team season. One for each season. I can place each of the last two years stats into a table with the following query:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT name, wins, losses, otl, pts, gf, ga FROM standings2014_2015 WHERE teamid = '".$_POST["teamid"]."'");
$result2 = $db->query("SELECT name, wins, losses, otl, pts, gf, ga FROM standings2015_2016 WHERE teamid = '".$_POST["teamid"]."'");
```

I am attempting to have a 3rd row that will add the wins losses etc.
Here are my two attempted queries:

```
$query3 = "SELECT name, wins, losses, otl, pts, gf, ga FROM standings2014_2015 WHERE teamid = '".$_POST["teamid"]."'
           UNION ALL
           SELECT name, wins, losses, otl, pts, gf, ga FROM standings2015_2016 WHERE teamid = '".$_POST["teamid"]."'";
           $result3 = $db->query($query3);
```

This one returns all the rows of data correctly, I just don't know how to add the values of the columns correctly. I wanted to do something like `$wins = $row['standings2015_2016.wins'] + $row['standings2014_2015'];`but I was pretty sure that wouldn't work so I tried this second query which doesn't work at all.

```
$query2 = "SELECT standings2015_2016.wins, standings2014_2015.wins, standings2015_2016.losses, standings2014_2015.losses,
           standings2015_2016.otl, standings2014_2015.otl, standings2015_2016.pts, standings2014_2015.pts, standings2015_2016.gf, standings2014_2015.gf 
           standings2015_2016.ga, standings2014_2015.ga 
           FROM standings2014_2015 WHERE teamid = '".$_POST["teamid"]."'
           LEFT JOIN standings2015_2016
           ON standings2014_2015.teamid = standings2015_2016.teamid";
```

**Here is the structure of both of my tables:** `CREATE TABLE 'standings2015_2016' ('teamid' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 'confid' INTEGER, 'divid' INTEGER, 'name' TEXT, 'wins' INTEGER, 'losses' INTEGER, 'otl' INTEGER, 'pts' INTEGER, 'gf' INTEGER, 'ga' INTEGER)` 
If you want to see what exactly I mean, click on this link and click on one of the teams [Here](http://52.4.65.161/final_project/standings.php)

Comment: which database are you connecting to?

Comment: `try {   
  $db = new PDO('sqlite:../../SharksDB/SharksDB');  
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
 } catch (Exception $e) {  
   echo "Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.";
   exit;
  }` PDO

Comment: i mean db name. Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: sqlite pdo in my browser

Comment: not sure about that but check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33195939/5234334)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I understood your request correctly:

```
"SELECT name, SUM(wins), SUM(losses), SUM(otl), SUM(pts), SUM(gf), SUM(ga) FROM
(SELECT name, wins, losses, otl, pts, gf, ga FROM standings2014_2015 WHERE teamid = '".$_POST["teamid"]."'
       UNION ALL
SELECT name, wins, losses, otl, pts, gf, ga FROM standings2015_2016 WHERE teamid = '".$_POST["teamid"]."')
GROUP BY name"
```

Comment: I think so? I ran this test and the way I am trying to echo the wins is not working. `$result3 = $db->query($query3);
  foreach ( $result3 as $row ) {
  $wins = $row['wins'];
  echo $wins;
  echo "test";
  }`

Comment: I changed it to `$wins = $row['SUM(wins)'];
  echo $wins;` The echo results in 650 when it should be 56. So it is adding two Integers as strings for me right now...

Comment: Your code worked when I added "standings2014_2015" at the end of the FROM() statement. I dunno if you want to edit that or not. Just giving you the heads up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd like to edit it, but I don't understand why is it necessary. The given alias to the union table is not used in your outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

use something like below. Format it in php terms.

```
"SELECT t1.name as name, t1.wins+t2.wins as wins, t1.losses+t2.losses as losses,t1.otl+t2.otl as otl, t1.pts=t2.pts as pts,
t1.gf=t2.gf as gf, t1.ga=t2.ga as ga
FROM standings2014_2015 t1 
inner join standings2015_2016 t2 
on t1.teamid=t2.teamid 
WHERE teamid = '".$_POST["teamid"]."'
```

Comment: I reduced it to `"SELECT standings2014_2015.wins + standings2015_2016.wins as wins
         FROM standings2014_2015 
         INNER JOIN standings2015_2016
          ON standings2014_2015.teamid = standings2015_2016.teamid
         WHERE teamid = '13'"` still not working

Comment: Use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and change db to SQLLite to create the table and some rows in it and then try running the sql.

Comment: I can test queries in my browser using sqlite. Anyways, I hope to mark one of you for an answer tomorrow. I need to give it a rest tonight though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: np. But if you try it in your browser, I cant see where is it going wrong. So use sqlfiddle tomorrow. You can share the link so everyone can see.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work finally. My solution was closest to Neria's solution

```
"SELECT teamid, name, SUM(wins) wins, SUM(losses) losses, SUM(otl) otl, SUM(pts) pts, SUM(gf) gf, SUM(ga) ga 
        FROM ( 
                SELECT *  FROM standings2014_2015 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT * FROM standings2015_2016
              ) standings2014_2015
        WHERE teamid = '".$_POST["teamid"]."'" ;
```

It was almost exactly the same as Neria's solution, however I needed to add "standings2014_2015" on the outside of the FROM() statement.